# How to link to a header that is only an external link?

Tags: org-mode

Say there is a file `a.org` with the following link as a header:

```
** [[./projects.html][Software & Services]]
```

How can it be linked to (from another file)?

`[[file:a.org::*Software & Services]]` did not work. Neither did `[[file:a.org::[[./projects.html][Software & Services]]]]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an automatic way of creating links with `org-store-link` (<kbd>C-c l</kbd>).

With the cursor on the header, call `org-store-link`. Then, on the link position, type <kbd>C-c C-l</kbd> (`org-insert-link`), and then <kbd>M-p</kbd> (or up arrow) to get the stored link and insert it. And it works!

The resulting documents are:

a.org:

```
** [[./projects.html][Software & Services]]
```

other_file.org:

```
** Somewhere else
This is a [[file:a.org::*%5B%5B./projects.html%5D%5BSoftware%20&%20Services%5D%5D][link]] to the first heading.
```

Note that this procedure automatically url-encodes your heading contents.

Comment: Do you mind if [the section about global commands](http://orgmode.org/manual/Activation.html#Activation) is added to your answer?